# First signer title gets blank when envelope goes to second signer

Tags: docusignapi

Below are the steps which I performed.

1. Create a draft envelope.
2. Update Signer 1 details.
3. Update title tab value using tabId.
4. Change the status of envelope to sent.
5. Create embedded url for Signer 1 (Signer 1 is able to his own title and Signer 2 title).
6. Once Signer 1 complete signing, Signer 2 receives mail.
7. Signer 2 open docusign envelope.(He can see his own title but not Signer 1 title).

What would be the issue that Signer 1 title is getting blank in step 7?

Comment: Is the problem with only title tab or are you facing this issue with other tab types (For ex: Text, DateSigned etc)

Comment: Can you please share your Api requests. Also see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38009218/1219543).. Not all tabs can be updated through the Api.

Comment: I am facing issue with title tab..I am able to see title when signer 1 signs but when signer 2 signs it gets disappeared.

Comment: Please show us your code to create the envelope. Also include the code of other API calls that you are making.

Comment: I just changed title tab to text tab and now my problem is solved.Thanks CodingDawg for help/

Comment: Welcome to stackOverflow. Please accept the answer if it addressed your question. See [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 0):

Title tab values cannot be updated through the API.  See this [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38009218/1219543) for more information.

A [text tab](https://docs.docusign.com/esign/restapi/Envelopes/EnvelopeRecipientTabs/) might be a better choice for your usecase.