# How to populate DocuSign Name field with something other than Sender name?

Tags: docusignapi

I'm using DocuSignAPI SDK to send envelopes. I have a few templates defined and they use a Custom Field called MemberFullName.

The field is of type Name, FullName.

For some templates I want MemberFullName map to a Signer's name, but sometimes I want to map another name to it.
My assumption was if I don't map anything to MemberFullName, then Signer's name will be used. But if I add "fullNameTabs" for MemberFullName, then it will be mapped.

```
Signer sgnr = new Signer()
{
RoleName = "Someone other than Member",
RecipientId = "1",
Name = "Bob Signer",
Email = "bobsemailaddress@yahoo.com"
};
sgnr.Tabs.FullNameTabs = new List<FullName>();
sgnr.Tabs.FullNameTabs.Add(new FullName() { TabLabel = "MemberFullName", Name = "Joe Smith" });
```

But MemberFullName is still mapped to Signer name in the resulting document.
How can I map a NON-SIGNER name to a field of type "Name"?

I know I can create a different field of type TEXT and map "Joe Smith" to it, but I wanted to reuse the "MemberFullName" field in both situations.
I apologize as I may not be using correct "docusign terminology" for things.

Answer (score 1):

You will not be able to set the value of FullName tab manually. See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38009218/1219543)
 for more information.