# docusign api tabs wont populate

Tags: rest, docusignapi

I've built a create envelope API call that has 7 tabs, I set the values but two fields will not populate. Company and Title are always blank. I set the tab labels programmatically from the /envelopes/{templateId} API request so I know it is correct.

```
    {
  "emailSubject": "Test Email",
  "emailBlurb": "This is for testing docusign api",
  "templateId": "cf5a9348-0d05-44ab-b0ac-8847303aa0ba",
  "templateRoles": [
    {
      "email": "swilliams@email.com",
      "name": "Shawn Williams",
      "roleName": "Signee",
      "tabs": {
        "fullNameTabs": [
          {
            "tabLabel": "Name 67755b0d-2284-4f20-acab-9ea4391f0e15",
            "value": "Shawn Williams"
          }
        ],
        "companyTabs": [
          {
            "tabLabel": "Company f9d5d265-9d97-42ba-a6ec-0d36f38b1017",
            "value": "SD"
          }
        ],
        "titleTabs": [
          {
            "tabLabel": "Title 35713ae4-3330-4864-b37c-066873fc0d6e",
            "value": "MR"
          }
        ],
        "ssnTabs": [
          {
            "tabLabel": "SSN",
            "value": "123-45-6789"
          }
        ],
        "firstNameTabs": [
          {
            "tabLabel": "F_Name",
            "value": "Shawn"
          }
        ],
        "lastNameTabs": [
          {
            "tabLabel": "L_Name",
            "value": "W"
          }
        ],
        "emailAddressTabs": [
          {
            "tabLabel": "Email",
            "value": "swilliams@email.org"
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  ],
  "transactionId": "test-20-id",
  "status": "sent"
}
```

Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not all DocuSign tabs can be populated. Some are calculated based on Recipients data and User Profile.

From [Documentation](https://www.docusign.com/developer-center/explore/features/stick-etabs) :

> Some tabs automatically populate with the recipient's data (such as *`emailTabs`* or *`fullNameTabs`*) while others require the signer to enter some information (*`textTabs`*) or make a choice (*`listTabs`*, *`checkboxTabs`*, *`radioGroupTabs`*).

If you want to populate data during envelope creation, **textTabs** might be a better choice.

Also see these related answers

- [Full list of tabs whose values can be set](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38009218/1219543)
- [Answer Two](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38022822/1219543)