# How do update document tabs for a recipient via DocuSign Rest API?

Tags: rest, docusignapi

I am attempting to use the the DocuSign REST API to update the value of a Text tab. The method I am using is PUT /v2/accounts/{accountId}/envelopes/{envelopeId}/recipients/{recipientId}/tabs

I am able to execute the method, I receive a success message from the DocuSign API, but the new value is not displayed in the document. I am passing in the account ID, evelopeID and recipient ID along with the tab ID (have also tried to use the tab label) in my request object that is passed to the API and in both scenarios the call completes with a success but the intended result of the tab value being updated does not occur.

Answer (score 0):

Not all tab values can be updated.Some are calculated based on Recipients data and User Profile.

See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38009218/1219543) for more information.

Also see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43881629/1219543)

If you are trying to update a tab whose value can indeed be updated, then please add your request json to the question so that we can take a look.

Comment: Please note that the tab in working with was noted in my post, "....he value of a Text tab" which is a tab that can be updated.

Comment: Can you please add the JSON request  to the question.